# ajax file upload on file choose IE problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, onchange

i am currently building an email attachment upload like the one from gmail.
i have a link to add new file inputs 
when the file is choosesn it should post it directly to my hidden iframe and show an progress bar and so on

in firefox, chrome, etc it works just great but in IE simply nothing works

i am working on this for several DAYS now ... i found up to 5 solutions on the internet but none of them worked, 
jquery change event doesnt work in ie for me,
my actual solution with click event and setTimeout doesnt work, 
i cant use flash uploads or other upload plugins, i am using jquery 1.6.2

this is the js code to create the input:
it works gread for ff, chrome and all the others but doesn't do anything in ie

```
var file = $(document.createElement("input"))
    .attr("type", "file")
    .attr("name", "attachment"+upload_number)

;
if ($.browser.msie){ 
    file.click( setTimeout( function() {
                                $("#uplform"+(upload_number-1)).submit();
                            }, 100));

}else{
    file.change(function() { 
                    $("#uplform"+(upload_number-1)).submit();
                });
    }
```

this is my html built in ff:

```
<div id="Uploads">
  <form id="uplform1" name="uplform1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"   target="uploadFrame1" action="/FileUploadServlet" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
    <input type="file" name="attachment1">
    <a href="javascript:removeFileInput('uplform1');">
      <img class="attachmenticon" src="/images/delete.jpg">
    </a>
    <div id="hiddendiv1" style="display: none;">
    <iframe id="uploadFrame1" name="uploadFrame1">
      <html><head></head><body>
      <script src="/jquery.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      <script src="/myAjaxScripts.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      <script>
        ajaxFunction()
      </script>
      </body></html>
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <img id="loadingbar1" class="attachmenticon" src="/images/green.png">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="UploadsLink" style="display:block;">
  <a href="javascript:addFileInput('/FileUploadServlet','');">Anhang hinzufügen</a>
</div>
```

thanks in advance